# Transfer Learning Custom Model after Training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

There are many models already trained on different tasks on Github for images, NLP, etc. How I can import the weights of these models and build a custom model on top of them? Should I build a model from scratch for them and match the number and shape of each layer or how I should proceed please?

For example, suppose I trained the CNN model below, then how to transfer it and use it later with other custom layers (different input shape for example)?

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10,
validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to save models like this: `model.save('my_model.h5')`
and load models like this: `new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')`
so summing you have a model from e.g. github in the *.h5 format just load it and than you can do `new_model.summary()` to see the model. when doing transfer learning you usually want to freeze the first layers and only train the last few layers which you can do with:
`new_model.trainable = False` to freeze the whole model and:

```
for layer in new_model.layers[-3:]:
    layer.trainable = True
```

to unfreeze the last three layers

Comment: Thank you.  I understand your point about first and last layers. 

1) So the model has to be in '.h5' format, please in order to transfer it and use it later?

Comment: *.h5 is just the standard keras file-format to save and load models it probably doesn't have to be in this format but it is the most common and you will most likely run in this format the most so i would recommend it

Comment: So Fin, if I train the model twice one using fine-tuning and then I followed it by transfer learning, does the model that I fitted will keep the weights I did in previous call to `model.fit()` please?